# How to add other language at Laragon?

Tags: laragon

I use a software namely "Laragon". it's software functionable as Web Server (as like XAMPP or WAMPP etc.)
and it give the user some feature as NodeJS. and in this case I wanna ask, how to add some language on Laragon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Laragon, you can easily add other language to your stack.
For example, if you want to add `Java`, just click **Menu > Tools > Quick add > java**

That's all.

Check:
Open Laragon Terminal, then type:

```
java -version
```

After adding, Java will be portable in Laragon.